# Is Wine installed default on Mint 17.1 Xfce, and is it safe to delete it if so?

Tags: linux-mint, wine, deleted-files

I was trying to install a game via Wine, but gave up on it. I've downloaded Wine from Software Manager. During installation Wine asked to download .NET packages, and I've done it. After I gave up trying to install my game, I went to Software Manager and deleted Wine. But I still have a `.wine` folder  in my home directory and it is not empty (200+ mb). So my question is, should I delete it and is it safe? (I do not know - maybe Wine was pre-installed with OS and it is not recommended to delete it).

In terminal I get this output:

```
oleg@oleg-X301A1 ~ $ Wine
No command 'Wine' found, did you mean:
 Command 'xine' from package 'xine-ui' (universe)
 Command 'line' from package 'util-linux' (main)
Wine: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the folder .wine because you have uninstalled Wine and are not planning to install it again. Lots of applications install the personal configuration in the persons home directory. A removal of the application leaves them untouched.

Comment: thanks. I've done this way http://sourcedigit.com/14942-completely-remove-wine-linux-ubuntu-systems/